# Simplest JPA criteria query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria

I've used hibernate for a long, now i started using JPA and i can't find a short way to write a simply select in less than seven lines (the use of criteria is a must in this project), is there a shorter way to build this query?

```
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Transaction> cq = cb.createQuery(Transaction.class);
    Root<Transaction> root = cq.from(Transaction.class);
    Collection<Predicate>  predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

    predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("originalOperationId"), originalOperationId));

    cq.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
    List<Transaction> resultado = em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    return resultado;
```

Comment: If it works, you should ask the question at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is working code and should be better ask at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: yes, you can put predicate directly to cq without wrapping it into list.

Comment: Ok, i can delete it and post there... but, what is stackoverflow for then?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for when your JPA query isn't working because you've made a mistake... or something else you can't seem to identify.

Comment: "What is stackoverflow for" - see that "help" menu at the top of the page?